# Codename One Builds Show Canceled by User in Dashboard

Tags: netbeans, codenameone

I'm trying out Codename One as a proof of concept for my company and tried to build the Kitchen Sink application using NetBeans 8.0.2. The build works properly and sends it to the web site but the dash board shows the build as "Canceled by User" every time. I have done the key and attached it to the application in case it was the issue and no longer get the key error in NetBeans but the builds still end the same. Anyone know what could be going wrong. I currently have the free account with 100 builds left.

Thanks
Don N.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create your project based on the Kitchen Sink demo and are trying to send an Android build?

If so read the bug section in this post:
http://www.codenameone.com/blog/javascript-port-cross-origin-hints-bugs.html

The demos are mostly for reference, they shouldn't be used as a starting point to an actual app especially not the highly bloated kitchen sink.

Comment: Thanks, I tried a simpler project and it worked fine.